# Responsive layout ordering with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a page with a Bootstrap layout like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
       content
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
       content A
       content B
   </div>
</div>
```

so that on larger screens, it looks like this:-

```
-----------------------
| content | content A |
|         | content B |
-----------------------
```

but on smaller screens, it looks like this:-

```
-------------
| content   |
| content A |
| content B |
-------------
```

How would I go about making that "content A" section appear at the very top on small screens, like this:-

```
-------------
| content A |
| content   |
| content B |
-------------
```

whilst keeping the larger version the same as above?

Comment: If you want `A` and `B` split up, why are they in the same container?

Comment: Good point. And the more I play with this, the more I see that that must be wrong. But what *should* it look like?!

Comment: I spent some time on it and don't have a solution. Your two layouts have different, conflicting requirements. The only solution may be scripting.

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion. I'll work something else out. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this HTML structure

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div>
        content A
        </div>
        <div class="d-block d-sm-block d-md-none">
            content
        </div>
        <div>
        content B
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work - but it does mean repeating the main "content" which isn't ideal.